# Two very similar lines of sed, can they be combined?

Tags: bash, sed

I have the following two lines in a shell script and was wondering if there was any way to condense them into one using sed. I am not sure if there is a wildcard or anything that could replace the words Glitch and Chill in these, but if there is, I'd like to know. All that really matters is that it removes everything in the weird brackets you see and nothing else is touched.

```
find . -type f -name '【Chill*' -execdir bash -c 'for file in "$@"; do new=$(echo "$file" | sed -r 's/【Chill.*】//'); mv -v "$file" "$new"; done' _ {} +  
find . -type f -name '【Glitch*' -execdir bash -c 'for file in "$@"; do new=$(echo "$file" | sed -r 's/【Glitch.*】//'); mv -v "$file" "$new"; done' _ {} +
```

Comment: Just curious: what generated those weird bolded/padded brackets `【】`? ([LEFT BLACK LENTICULAR BRACKET](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3010) and [RIGHT BLACK LENTICULAR BRACKET](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3011).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know you can done all by using Perl's rename:

```
$ rename -n 's:【Chill.*】|【Glitch.*】::' 【Chill* 【Glitch*
【Chillxx】file1.ext  renamed as file1.ext
【Chillyy】file2.ext  renamed as file2.ext
【Glitchxx】file3.ext renamed as file3.ext
【Glitchyy】file4.ext renamed as file4.ext
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f -name '【Chill*' -o -name '【Glitch*' -execdir bash -c 
'for file in "$@"; do 
   new=$(echo "$file" | sed -r 's/【Chill.*】\|【Glitch.*】//');
   mv -v "$file" "$new";
 done' _ {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of [@Cyrus](https://superuser.com/users/340330/cyrus) is good, but it would be even better without `sed`,
and with simplified `for` loop:

```
find . -type f -name '【Chill*' -o -name '【Glitch*' -execdir bash -c 
'for file; do 
   new=${file/【Chill*】/};
   new=${new/【Glitch*】/};
   mv -v "$file" "$new";
 done' _ {} +
```